# Some links and joints don't appear when running Gazebo with ROS2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, urdf

I'm running Gazebo Classic and ROS2 foxy.

This is the URDF file which is meant to display two boxes connected by a revolute joint. However, when launched with ROS2 the big_box link and the axel joint does not appear.

Is there anything that I'm missing and need to fix?

```
ros2 launch motor launch_urdf_into_gazebo.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/neil/.ros/log/2023-08-12-19-57-44-873235-ubuntu-20-24477
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [24480]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [24482]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-3]: process started with pid [24484]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [24486]
[INFO] [rviz2-5]: process started with pid [24497]
[robot_state_publisher-4] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-4] Link big_box had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-4] Link small_box had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1691895465.185255084] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1691895465.185296873] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment big_box
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1691895465.185300742] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment small_box
[spawn_entity.py-3] [INFO] [1691895465.399333515] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-3] [INFO] [1691895465.399706698] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-3] [INFO] [1691895465.401503989] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-3] [INFO] [1691895465.548803948] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-3] [INFO] [1691895465.549000775] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1691895465.558112057] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1691895465.558387589] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 3.1 (GLSL 1.4)
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1691895465.635010931] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[spawn_entity.py-3] [INFO] [1691895466.054977730] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-3] [INFO] [1691895466.242171620] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [motor]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 24484]
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="motor" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">


  <link name="base_footprint"/>
  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_footprint"/>
    <child link="big_box" />
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint> 


  <link name="big_box">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.166667" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.166667" iyz="0" izz="0.166667"/>
      <origin rpy="0 -0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </inertial>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 -0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 1 1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="grey">
        <lighting>1</lighting>
        <shader type="pixel">
          <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
        </shader>
        <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
        <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
        <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <link name="small_box">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.166667" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.166667" iyz="0" izz="0.166667"/>
      <origin rpy="0 -0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </inertial>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 -0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue">
        <lighting>1</lighting>
        <shader type="pixel">
          <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
        </shader>
        <ambient>0.3 0.3 1 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>0.7 0.7 1 1</diffuse>
        <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
        <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="axel" type="revolute">
    <parent link="big_box"/>
    <child link="small_box"/>
    <origin rpy="0 -0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="-1" lower="-1.79769e+308" upper="1.79769e+308" velocity="-1"/>
    <dynamics damping="0" friction="0" spring_reference="0" spring_stiffness="0"/>
  </joint>
  <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
</robot>
```

[image: gazebo missing links]

Answer (score 1):

your model doesn't have any collision, As you can see the `base_foot_print` and `small_box` links appears in the left menu as well as the joint.

You have two options:

- Add a collision to your models
- Make one of them static